# How to change Spring Boot starter dependency to newer version in Maven?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I need to update library's version to the latest because of vulnerability. For example, I have a starter (but it can be related not only to starter, it can be any library that relates on other libraries) in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-example</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It has 2 libraries that I need to update: library-a and library-b.
For the first library I set version in properties, and it has updated in project:

```
<properties>
   <library-a.version>2.0</library-a.version>
</properties>
```

But for the second library this way didn't help. So I excluded this library and imported a newer version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-example</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                *<exclusion>
                    <groupId>library-b</groupId>
                    <artifactId>library-b</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>*
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>library-b</groupId>
            <artifactId>library-b</artifactId>
            <version>**2.0**</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is it the right way to update libraries (especially I am worrying about **library-b**)? What issues can I face? I am afraid that my application can catch some bugs because of this replacement.
Unit tests passed, the application works locally.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you want to update a transient dependency like your library-b, you can either do what you do or update the parent and hope they have updated the version there.

If you can update the parent, it probably is better but it doesn't always solve the issue.

Now, you can hit some conflicting version where the parent uses the transient dependency with a method or class that does not exist in the new version. In this case, nothing you can do except submit a fix to the parent.

As a rule of thumb, if library-b update is only a minor or patch (no update in the first number of the version), it should work without issues. Furthermore, if it works locally and tests are passing, you should be fine but there are, of course, no "sure thing" here.